# IllegalStateException : content has been consumed android

Tags: java, android, exception, http-post

I am getting:

> IllegalStateException content has been consumed

***This is my code***

```
private String postRequest(String strRequestURL,HashMap<String, Object> dataParams,HashMap<String, Object> headerParams){
        String strResponse = "no resp";
        HttpPost httpPost;
        HttpClient httpClient;
        HttpParams httpParams;
        try {                   
            httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10*60*1000);//10 min
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10*60*1000);//10 min
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            httpPost = new HttpPost(strRequestURL);//new HttpPost(requestURL);
            Iterator iterHeader =headerParams.entrySet().iterator(); //postHeaderParams.entrySet().iterator(); 
            while (iterHeader.hasNext()) {      
                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iterHeader.next();
                httpPost.setHeader(mEntry.getKey().toString(), mEntry.getValue().toString());
            }


            Iterator iter =dataParams.entrySet().iterator(); 
            JSONObject objParams = new JSONObject();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {                    
                Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
                //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(mEntry.getKey().toString(), mEntry.getValue().toString()));
                objParams.put(mEntry.getKey().toString(),mEntry.getValue().toString());
            }
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(objParams.toString(), "UTF-8"));


            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode==200)
            {
                Log.i("log", "connection code status true");
            }
            strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity,HTTP.UTF_8);
        } 


        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Common.logError(context , ex.getMessage(), "API call - " + strRequestURL, "postRequest");
        }
        return strResponse;
    }
```

I am not able to find the exact problem from where the content is consumed.

*I have followed these links but no luck:*

[IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727114/illegalstateexception-content-has-been-consumed)

[IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed using httpPost to get data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280278/illegalstateexception-content-has-been-consumed-using-httppost-to-get-data-from)

[Android HttpResponse - Content has been consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168617/android-httpresponse-content-has-been-consumed)

["IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183343/illegalstateexception-content-has-been-consumed-probem)

[IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed - How to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745915/illegalstateexception-content-has-been-consumed-how-to-resolve)

Comment: In which line you get this exception? Stacktrace?

Comment: strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity,HTTP.UTF_8);

The last line of try block

Comment: @donfuxx please suggest me any solution for this. I am stuck in this issue

Comment: please suggest any solution for this guys